# templated service dependency on systemd

Tags: systemd, services

I have some templated Base Services. Let's call them `basis@foo.service`, `basis@bar.service` (and optionally more `basis@xyz.service`) . And I have a more complex service which should be started after all of these Base Services. Let's call this service `complex.service`

How can I make the `complex.service` start after all base services are started?
What is the correct way for the file `complex.service`?

```
[Unit]
After=basis@.service
...
```

or

```
[Unit]
After=basis@*.service
...
```

Answer (score 1):

`After` takes just a list of unit names, so it is `After=basis@foo.service basis@bar.service basis@xyz.service`, or from the other end `Before=complex.service` in `basis@.service`.

Comment: In my Case: The List of the units for `After=...` is not completely known at the moment of writing the `complex.service` file.

Comment: @powerpete Then go with `Before`?